# Error when creating a topic in Apache Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

Does anyone knows how to fix the error when creating a topic in Kafka?

```
C:\kafka\bin\windows>kafka-topics.bat --create --bootstrap-server localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partition 1 --topic test
Exception in thread "main" joptsimple.UnrecognizedOptionException: partition is not a recognized option
        at joptsimple.OptionException.unrecognizedOption(OptionException.java:108)
        at joptsimple.OptionParser.handleLongOptionToken(OptionParser.java:510)
        at joptsimple.OptionParserState$2.handleArgument(OptionParserState.java:56)
        at joptsimple.OptionParser.parse(OptionParser.java:396)
        at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$TopicCommandOptions.<init>(TopicCommand.scala:567)
        at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$.main(TopicCommand.scala:47)
        at kafka.admin.TopicCommand.main(TopicCommand.scala)
```

Comment: the error is already explained in the log of your screenshot, and as answred below you're using zookeeper port in "boostrap-server" so you could use the deprecated way "--zookeeper localhost:2181" or the new way "--bootstrap-server:localhost:9092" if your broker is listening in this port

Answer (score 0):

The parameter is partition**s**

The bootstrap server normally (default) runs in port **9092**

C:\kafka\bin\windows>kafka-topics.bat --create --bootstrap-server localhost:**9092** --replication-factor 1 --partition**s** 1 --topic test

Answer (score 0):

In recent versions, you don't have to create topics on zookeeper. You can directly create topics on the bootstrap servers of Kafka. In the later version, they plan to remove the zookeeper altogether, so they are preparing for that in the current versions.

Use the below to create a new partition. I suggest adding the below parameters as well to control the topic behaviour appropriately.

```
kafka-topics.bat --create --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --partitions 1 --replication-factor 1 --config retention.ms=604800000 segment.bytes=26214400 retention.bytes=1048576000 min.insync.replicas=1 --topic test
```